# How would I get the base address of a process and edit that pointer with it?

Tags: c#, memory

I thought base addresses where meant to be like **0x00** but when i use a button to give me the base address i get this **1966604288**. I'm using the Vam Memory DLL. The problem might also be i dont know how to use ida to get memory addresses..
Note: I've tried kernel32.dll and user32.dll

```
        public IntPtr GetModuleBaseAddress(string processName, string moduleName)
        {

            Process process;

            try
            {
                process = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)[0];
            }

            catch (IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {

                throw new ArgumentException($"No process with name {processName} is currently running");
            }



            var module = process.Modules.Cast<ProcessModule>().SingleOrDefault(m => string.Equals(m.ModuleName, moduleName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));


            return module?.BaseAddress ?? IntPtr.Zero;
        }






        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            vam.processName = "the process im using";
            IntPtr baseaddy = GetModuleBaseAddress("the process im using", "user32.dll");
            int addy = 0xFD1117;
            vam.WriteInt32((IntPtr)baseaddy + addy, 1000);
            richTextBox1.Text = baseaddy.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

That's not all my code but it should be enough.

Comment: hi Sweetpeps,it would nice to know if the solution below answered your question completely/partially.  if you think it has not, then I might have misinterpreted your query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address that begins with *0x* is the *Hex* value you are referring to which you can obtain by with a suffix like `BaseAddress.ToString("x8")`

*Output*: *The process's main module's base address is: 0x00a80000*

---

**Snippet**: *Retrieves Base Address of every module associated with the Notepad Process and prints Main Modules Base address in Hex representation*

```
using (Process myProcess = new Process())
{
   ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
   myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
   myProcess.Start();
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
   ProcessModule myProcessModule;

   Console.WriteLine("Base addresses of the modules associated "+"with 'notepad' are:");
   for (int i = 0; i < myProcess.Modules.Count; i++)
   {
      myProcessModule = myProcess.Modules[i];
      Console.WriteLine(myProcessModule.ModuleName + " : " + (IntPtr)myProcessModule.BaseAddress);
   }

   Console.WriteLine("The process's main module's base address is: 0x"+myProcess.MainModule.BaseAddress.ToString("x8"));
   myProcess.CloseMainWindow();
}
```